# access vba string that references multiple numeric items in a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

So I am writing a string in VBA. It needs to use 2 different numeric variables from a form that the user clicked on. My code works great if I only use 1 variable, but I can't get the syntax correct for 2 variables. Here is what I originally wrote that works fine.

```
stringSQL = "select table1.field1, table2.field2 from table1 where table1.flag='flag' and 
table1.weight = " & [Forms]![myform]![weight]
```

When I try to add age to the string (I want to use age and weight from myform) I write this which does not work -

```
stringSQL = "select table1.field1, table2.field2 from table1 where table1.flag='flag' and 
table1.age= " & [Forms]![myform]![age] & " and " & table1.weight= " & 
[Forms]![myform]![weight]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
stringSQL = "select table1.field1, table2.field2 " & _
            " from table1 where table1.flag='flag' " & _
            " and table1.age= " & [Forms]![myform]![age] & _
            " and table1.weight= " & [Forms]![myform]![weight]
```

Comment: ahh thanks a million, i've been stuck on this problem for hours! I thought the & symbol meant concatenate, why is it that mine is incorrect and your works?

Comment: In your example you have `table1.weight` outside of the literal string part of the expression.